# Interesting example of different Lawvere theories on a category

Tags: logic, category-theory, universal-algebra

A Lawvere theory on a category $C$ is a functor $L:\aleph_0^\text{op}\to C$ preserving finite products which is a bijection on objects, where $\aleph_0^\text{op}$ is the skeletal category of finite sets.

> What is an example of a category $C$ and two different lawvere theory structures on $C$?

I can imagine that simple examples can be obtained by freely adjoining some arrows to the category $\aleph_0^\text{op}$ to get ${\aleph_0'}^\text{op}$ and look for finite product preserving functors $\aleph_0^\text{op}\to{\aleph_0'}^\text{op}$. However I have little to no intuition for what this means, which is why I am asking for an "interesting" example of this.

However, I am also suspicious of my claim because my understanding is that a model of a Lawvere theory $L:\aleph_0^\text{op}\to C$ are finite product preserving functors $C\to \mathcal Sets$, which do not depend on the choice of $L$. This would mean that two different Lawvere theories have the same models, which feels wrong to me.

My conclusion is that either my claim is wrong, and the structure of a Lawvere theory on $C$ is uniquely determined, or my understanding of Lawvere theories is flawed.

Comment: That is an unusual definition of Lawvere theory... I would say that this is where the confusion comes from

Comment: I agree with Max - where did you find that definition? If you additionally require that $L$ is essentially surjective, then I would agree that this is a reasonable definition of Lawvere theory.

Comment: @Max This is the one given on wikipedia for [Lawvere theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawvere_theory). Oops, I forgot to mention that $L$ should be a bijection on objects, sorry.

Comment: @Couchy311 Right, the bijection condition is crucial! In general, if you refer to a definition, it's really helpful to cite the source of the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functor $L$ in your definition is often assumed to be the identity on objects. In that case it's definitely uniquely determined, because the only morphisms of $ℵ_0^{\mathrm{op}}$ are tuples of projections, which are preserved by $L$ since it preserves products. You can also ask for $L$ to be essentially surjective instead, in which case it won't be uniquely determined in general, but it will be unique up to isomorphism, which isn't substantially different.

Calling any functor $L : ℵ_0^{\mathrm{op}} → C$ which preserves finite products a Lawvere theory doesn't make much sense.

In any case, $L$ is just a matter of convenience, all the required data is already present in $C$. You can just as well say that a Lawvere theory is a category $C$ with distinct objects $\{T_0, T_1, T_2, ...\}$, such that $T_n = T_1^n$. It's basically the same thing.

While it doesn't make sense to speak about two different Lawvere theories "on" $C$, it makes sense to ask if two different Lawvere theories $C$ and $D$ can have equivalent categories of models. The answer is most definitely yes, and the question an important one. Such equivalence is called Morita Equivalence of theories, because it directly generalizes the Morita equivalence of rings. For example, Lawvere theores for right $ℝ$-modules and right $M_nℝ$-modules are certainly different, but the categories of models are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was suspecting. I forgot to mention the bijection on objects. I believe my confusion came from the fact that I saw someone define "the category of Lawvere theory structures on a category $C$". I was having trouble understanding why bother doing such a thing if that category was trivial, but in the end I think the reason this was done was to show that some other category of equivalent structures on $C$ is also trivial.